# A question related to reflection principle

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

**Question:**

$$P(X_1\gt 0, ..., X_n\gt 0, X_n=a-b)=?$$

---

**Its Answer:**

$= (1,1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b) $ that meet  neither touch nor cross paths.

$=[(1,1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b) \ \ \text{all paths}]-[(1,1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b)  \ \text{that meet  touch or cross paths.}]$

$$=[(1,1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b) \ \ \text{all paths}]-[(1,-1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b) \ \ \text{all paths}]$$

$$=\binom{n-1}{n-1+a-b-1\over 2}-\binom{n-1}{n-1+a-b+1\over 2}$$

$$=\binom{a+b-1}{a-1}-\binom{a+b-1}{a}$$

where $n=a+b$

I have used reflection principe that $= (1,1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b) $ that meet  touch or cross paths. equal to $(1,-1)   \rightarrow (n,a-b) \ \ \text{all paths}$

---

**My real question:**

But if I have
$$P(X_1\ge 0, ..., X_n\ge 0, X_n=a-b)=?$$ how can I solve this question like my above solution. How can I use reflection principle? Please explain it. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any path $P$ from $(0,0)$ to $(n,a-b)$. By adding a $+1$ step from $(-1,-1)$ to $(0,0)$ we now have a path $P^{'}$ of length $n+1$ from $(-1,-1)$ to $(n,a-b)$. We now shift path $P^{'}$ one unit up and one unit right, giving us a path $P^{''}$ from $(0,0)$ to $(n+1,a-b+1)$.

Now, for $i\geq 1,\;$ $P$ has all its $X_i\geq 0\;$ iff $\;P^{''}$ has all its $X_i\gt 0$.

So we can use your previous result, replacing $a$ with $a+1$, to count the number of paths $P^{''}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \#\{\text{paths $P$ with $X_1\geq 0,\ldots,X_{n}\geq 0, X_{n}=a-b$}\} \\
&& \quad = \#\{\text{paths $P^{''}$ with $X_1\gt 0,\ldots,X_{n+1}\gt 0, X_{n+1}=a-b+1$}\} \\
&& \quad = \binom{a+b}{a} - \binom{a+b}{a+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}